# How can I @Autowire a Spring @Repository which is form an external jar

Tags: spring, maven, autowired

I have imported an external jar ( which is also written by me ) form sonatype nexus. I want to use a repository from that jar ( which is annotated with @Repository) in one of my classes in this project.
The import is successful but even if I add

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
"package.of.the.bean"
})
```

It still throws an exception saying that the bean could not be found.

Comment: What kind of repository. A Spring Data based one or a normal component? If the latter what you have should work, if the first you need an `@Enable*Repositories` and point that to the package.

Comment: I am importing a database configuration from that module also - which has EnableJpaRepositories. I guess that dosen't work ? I need to do a database configuration on each module ?

Comment: With a few adjustments it worked with your solution. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ComponentScan` annotation with external package value.

`@ComponentScan("external.package")`

Answer (score 0):

@EnableJpaRepositories did the trick.